# Localization JSF Message Bundle's Parameter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, localization

How can I use message bundle's parameter by local?

Example :

```
<p:inputText id="age" required="true">
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="5"/>
</p:inputText>
```

If I input the value less than `5`, `JSF` will show up

For Eng :   `Please enter greater than or equal to 5`

For Japanese :   `以上を入力してください 5`

For Myanmar : အနည်းဆုံး တန်ဖိုး 5 ဖြစ်ရပါမည်

In Japanese message, I want to show **Japanese Kanji or Hiragana number**

```
`五` or `ご`.
```

In Myanmar Message, I want to show "၅" instance of "5".

But, JSF message bundle's parameter is only support Eng locale.
Will I need to write custom validator and converter? If so, I have to write a lot of.

I just only want to the number.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your value in message bundle expect a parameter because you've used this text representation in several cases (e.g. other input text areas with at least 10 characters)? Otherwise I would suggest to add your text in a static way, so you don't have to rely on parameters.

If you insist on a dynamic solution then have a look at the following utf-8 chartable:

www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=4096&number=128&utf8=string-literal

There you find for each character the specified utf-8 encoding. You can display differents formats and encoding types, whatever you're looking for. For your numbers in Myanmar I have selected the following:

```
Unicode code point | character | UTF-8 (in literal) | name
----------------------------------------------------------
U+1040  ၀   \xe1\x81\x80    MYANMAR DIGIT ZERO
U+1041  ၁   \xe1\x81\x81    MYANMAR DIGIT ONE
U+1042  ၂   \xe1\x81\x82    MYANMAR DIGIT TWO
U+1043  ၃   \xe1\x81\x83    MYANMAR DIGIT THREE
U+1044  ၄   \xe1\x81\x84    MYANMAR DIGIT FOUR
U+1045  ၅   \xe1\x81\x85    MYANMAR DIGIT FIVE
U+1046  ၆   \xe1\x81\x86    MYANMAR DIGIT SIX
U+1047  ၇   \xe1\x81\x87    MYANMAR DIGIT SEVEN
U+1048  ၈   \xe1\x81\x88    MYANMAR DIGIT EIGHT
U+1049  ၉   \xe1\x81\x89    MYANMAR DIGIT NINE
```

I hope this helps!